# Postgres django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

Trying to run my django server in a docker, but the postgres port is already being used? When I run "docker-compose up", I receive this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py migrate' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

> sudo service postgresql status

returns:

```
9.6/main (port 5432): online
```

> sudo lsof -nP | grep LISTEN

returns:

```
postgres  15817         postgres    3u     IPv4            1022328        0t0        TCP 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I tried to run "sudo kill -9 15817", but docker-compose up still receives the same error.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'stemletics',
        'USER': 'stemleticsadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'changeme',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # set in docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': 5432 # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your docker-compose file. Likely you will need to add `network_mode: "host"` to the django service in the docker-compose file.

Comment: I added my docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Is your goal to run postgres inside of Docker? Or to have it managed using service?

Comment: My end goal is to have my website running inside elastic beanstalk on AWS. I would think outside? Then I could have multiple dockers that would query one database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between localhost and postgres for host in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635352/difference-between-localhost-and-postgres-for-host-in-docker)

Answer (score 8):

In order to use postgres inside of Docker you will need to configure information like the database user, password and db-name. This is done through setting environment variables for the container. A complete list of supported variables can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

Additionally you will want to expose port `5432` of postgres to your `web` service inside your `docker-compose` file.

Something like this should work:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=stemletics
      - POSTGRES_USER=stemleticsadmin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

You will also have to change the hostname you are using inside `settings.py`. `docker-compose` creates a default network for your services and attaches the running containers to this network. Inside your web container the database will be available at the hostname `db`.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'stemletics',
        'USER': 'stemleticsadmin',
        'PASSWORD': 'changeme',
        'HOST': 'db', # set in docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': 5432 # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Lastly if you do not have any sort of database reconnection logic in your python code the migration may still fail. This is due to the fact that `depends_on` only waits for the container to start, but postgres will take a couple of seconds to initialze after the container is running.

In order to get around this quickly it will be easiest to run one container at a time.

i.e.:

`$ docker-compose up -d db`

*Wait for postgres to initialize*

`$ docker-compose up -d web`

Hopefully this gets you up and running.

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Comment: Is the python code that has this error running inside docker, and if it is was it started with `docker-compose`?

Comment: docker-compose up was the command that i ran to receive that, so your saying that the python code is running inside the docker.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue simply building my db container, wait few seconds, then building the web container:

`docker-compose up -d --build db`

*wait a few seconds*

`docker-compose up -d --build web`

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**I face the same problem to connect the PostgreSQL server to the windows operating system. Then I apply the following way. I hope it will help to solve this problem...**

1. Download [postgres_sql](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)
2. Install postgresql
3. Search option open 'SQL Shell (psql)'
4. Create database

[image]

5. Settings add DATABASES....

**settings.py**

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'stemletics',
        'USER': 'postgres', #default user name
        'PASSWORD': 'changeme',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', # default host
        'PORT': '5432', # default postgres port
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it turned out that I hadn't started docker desktop. Apparently, if docker desktop is not running, any docker commands you use do not apply to docker desktop but rather a different version of docker on your system. My OS is ubuntu 22.04.